# Opal: Ruby to Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, opal

I learned about Opal for Ruby recently and would like to convert a Ruby file to Javascript.  I've used Coffeescript before, and I can compile a Coffeescript file to Javascript with a certain command on Node.js.  How do I do the same with Ruby and Opal to Javascript ?

Comment: Actually Opan compile Ruby to JS, did you mean JS to Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

To compile your Ruby to JavaScript:

```
opal -c program.rb > program.js
```

`-c` means "compile to JavaScript" (as opposed to "execute now"); the JavaScript is written to the standard output, so you can use redirection to capture it to a file.